Dependency issues installing python package from Artifact Registry
I'm trying to install a private Python package from Artifact Registry in GCP, but I'm getting some dependency errors that only happens when I try to install it using pip and keyrings.
I'm able to download the .tag.gz file from the artifactory and then install it manually from my local environment running: pip install pkg-0.0.1.tar.gz
But when I try to follow the process to install the package using pip and keyrings it raises dependency issues such as the one below:
$ pip install --no-cache-dir --index-url https://location-python.pkg.dev/project/pkg/simple/ pkg 
Looking in indexes: https://location-python.pkg.dev/project/pkg/simple/
Collecting pkg
  Downloading https://location-python.pkg.dev/project/pkg/pkg/pkg-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (13.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 13.6/13.6 MB 11.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pkg to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement autoflake<3.0.0,>=2.3.1 (from pkg) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for autoflake<3.0.0,>=2.3.1

After removing autoflake I encounter the same error but now for backoff package: ERROR: No matching distribution found for backoff<3.0.0,>=2.2.1
Since I can install the same package manually I guarantee that the publishing step is working fine (current using Poetry), so it must be something related to the installation process.
The current installation process is as follows:
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=creds.json
pip install --no-cache-dir keyring keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth
pip install --no-cache-dir --index-url https://location-python.pkg.dev/project/pkg/simple/ pkg

Any help?

Does https://location-python.pkg.dev/project/pkg/simple/ provide autoflake and backoff ?  pip install pkg-0.0.1.tar.gz will look on pypi for dependencies. pip install --no-cache-dir --index-url https://location-python.pkg.dev/project/pkg/simple/ pkg  will look only in https://location-python.pkg.dev/project/pkg/simple/. Maybe try with --extra-index-url https://location-python.pkg.dev/project/pkg/simple/ instead

Good point @FlyingTeller, I changed to --extra-index-url but now I'm getting this very weird error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch', the error is longer than that but it ends at that point. I say "weird" because it's not being used in the package, not even mentioned.

There's a package named with the same name of my custom package in Pypi which is being installed before mine, using --extra-index-url, so in this case I think the best solution is to make the other packages available within my custom package and continue to use --index-url
